# How to properly quote variables, which are then no longer considered if omitted

Tags: shell-script

I am a bit at a loss right now as to why a script of mine does not work as I perceived it.

Since `id3v2` is a bit complex to use, I tried to simplify its uses by writing a script around it.  The parts which are mine work perfectly fine, but coming to handing the collected information over to `id3v2`, it fails when any of the switch values have spaces in there, even though I forced quotations inside the variables.

The usage for `id3v2` requires each switch to be followed by a value.  Everything else is considered a file.

So, in order to define the title the switch would look like this:

```
--TIT2 "Beautiful Stranger"
```

The switch without and the value with quotation marks to cope with whitespace.

To be able to fully omit any switch without building a new command line inside the script, I thought it would be smart to submit the variables without quotations with forced quotations inside the value, which I hoped where unwrapped.  Consider the following:

```
...
sTitle="--TIT2 \"Beautiful Stranger\""
...
/usr/bin/id3v2 ${sTitle} ${sArtist} ${sAlbum} ${sTrack} ${sYear} ${sGenre} ${sGrouping} "${aFiles[${iFile}]}"
```

However, while the result looks good using the above line with `echo`, using `id3v2` provides me the message `Couldn't stat file 'Stranger"'` (basically, the second part of my title plus finalizing quotation cannot be found, which is obviously correct).

Disappointed that `id3v2` apparently does not adhere to the unwrapped forced quotations, I modified my script to split the variables from the switches and quoted them on the target command line instead:

```
...
sTitleHead="--TIT2"
sTitle="Beautiful Stranger"
...
/usr/bin/id3v2 "${sTitleHead}" "${sTitle}" "${sArtistHead}" "${sArtist}" "${sAlbumHead}" "${sAlbum}" "${sTrackHead}" "${sTrack}" "${sYearHead}" "${sYear}" "${sGenreHead}" "${sGenre}" "${sGroupingHead}" "${sGrouping}" "${aFiles[${iFile}]}"
```

This works as long as all variables are used, but fails if one (or more) variables are omitted.  The error message there is `Couldn't stat file ''`.  It seems that it still finds the quotes on the command line and tries them as a file name, even though when I omit a variable, I typically unset or set them as zero-length string (tried both).

I also tried to remove quotations from my `...Head` variables, just in case they are not properly detected as parameters, but the result is the same.

Does anyone know how to convince `id3v2` on how to take the command line parameters without giving out?

Alternatively, if there is a easier scriptable program around, I am also thankful.

Comment: You should store options like this in an array instead of a variable.

Comment: Hmm...  I will give it a try.  Have not thought of that indeed.

Comment: Another possibility is to use conditional expansion, like `/usr/bin/id3v2 ${sTitle:+ --TIT2 "${sTitle}"}`, which leaves out both the flag and (double-quoted) arg if `sTitle` is undefined. See my answer to [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1245822/curl-add-string-as-option-in-bash).

Comment: @Jesse_b That seems to have worked indeed now.  As it did not work initially, I am still wondering what the difference between `${aOptions[*]}` and `${aOptions[@]}` is.  I was under the impression that they were interchangeable.

Comment: @GordonDavisson a neat alternative solution.  Though I agree that the array version of Jesse_b definitely sounds like something I will use in the future more often.

Comment: @Phoenix You want `"${aOptions[@]}"` to expand the array; both the double-quotes  and `@` are required for it to work right.

Comment: @GordonDavisson that is what I found out as well. ;-)  The question (inside the comments) remains, however.

Comment: Without double-quotes, `${aOptions[*]}` and `${aOptions[@]}` are equivalent. With double-quotes they're quite a bit different: `*` merges all array elements into a single string, but `@` treats each element as a separate string. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348443/a-confusion-about-array-versus-array-in-the-context-of-a-bash-comple/3348659#3348659) for details.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Perfect!  Thanks!  That is clear then.

Comment: @Jesse_b Thanks to you, of course, as well for pointing me to the answer.  The suggestions did not hold it, so I posted mine.  Thanks again!